# "method ... is not applicable" occurs when inferring method generics inside generic class

Tags: generics, java-8, type-inference

I'm trying to bind an HK2 factory in Jersey, and the compiler is producing strange errors about its inability to find an appropriate method overload. The error seems to be related to inferring generic types, but even when I explicitly specify the generics, it still doesn't seem to like it. I would expect the following example code to compile:

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;

public class TestFeature<K> implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bindFactory(MyFactory.class).to(String.class);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    private class MyFactory implements Factory<String> {

        @Override
        public String provide() {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose(String instance) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

and if I change `TestFeature<K>` to `TestFeature` (i.e., make the outer class non-generic), it does. However, as-is I get the following error with `bindFactory()`:

```
method org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder.<T>bindFactory(java.lang.Class<? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<T>>) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<zone.fur.mongo.TestFeature.MyFactory> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory<T>>))
```

Even if I explicitly bind `T`:

```
this.<String>bindFactory(MyFactory.class).to(String.class);
```

then the error persists (although, my IDE does not highlight it as an error in either case).

Can someone shed some light on why `TestFeature` being generic causes the type inference to break, and what I can do to fix it or work around it? (In my actual code, I managed to refactor some things and make the outer class non-generic, which made the problem go away, but I'd still like to know what is going on here and why it doesn't behave as I'm expecting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MyFactory` wasn’t declared `static`, it has an enclosing instance of type `TestFeature<K>`, so for correct generic operations the actual type of `K` is needed. Keep in mind that `MyFactory.class` is short-hand for `TestFeature.MyFactory.class`; this abbreviation is possible because `MyFactory` is in scope. You would need something like `TestFeature<A>.MyFactory.class` with `A` being the actual type for `K`, but unfortunately it is impossible for `Class` objects to capture actual type parameters.

So the solution is either, don’t make the outer class generic, or declare `MyFactory` as `static` if it doesn’t have a dependency to a parametrized outer type. Being able to remove `<K>` without getting new compiler errors suggests that `K` is not used inside `MyFactory`. It might also be possible to split the functionality of the outer class into two. If the outer class is a non-generic subtype of a generic type, like `MyFactory` is, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore that override compile error. This looks like a bug in Eclipse IDE.
I tried this code and it worked perfectly fine.

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.Factory;
import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;


public class TestFeature<K> implements Feature {

    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {      
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Feature f = new TestFeature<String>();
        System.out.println(f.configure(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse (I'm using IntelliJ), and I'm not having issues with `@Override` (assuming this is what you mean by "override compile error"). The issue is with the `bindFactory` call.